# error while change the date format

Tags: r

For the dataset below, I want to change the date format to YYYY-mm-dd:

```
DATE          WT
30 Dec 2016   1150.9
29 Dec 2016   1157.67
28 Dec 2016   1141.03
27 Dec 2016   1138.49
26 Dec 2016   1132.72
23 Dec 2016   1133.57
```

I am using as.Date(DATE, "%d.%m.%Y"), but it is not working.

Can there be other method?

Comment: Which technology you are using PHP or Java?

Comment: I am using `R` and not PHP or Java. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `%b` instead of `%m`

```
df1$DATE <- as.Date(df1$DATE, "%d %b %Y")
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun  when I tried this, i got .. `Error in as.Date.default(df$DATE, "%d %b %Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'df$DATE' to class “Date”`

Comment: @MadhuSareen  I am getting the correct output  `as.Date("30 Dec 2016", "%d %b %Y")#
[1] "2016-12-30"`

Comment: I checked there are white spaces after 2016, I guess the reason why I got the errors

Comment: @MadhuSareen  Then use `as.Date(trimws(df1$DATE, "%d %b %Y")`

Comment: i guess `)` is missing. anyways, I tried and i got `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "DATE", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 260`

Comment: I got the answer... `DF <- as.data.frame(apply(DF, 2, function (x) sub("\\s+$", "", x)))
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, format="%d %b %Y")`